# How do you add < or > to a summary tag in Visual studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, comments

How do you add < (less than) or > (greater than) to a summary comment in visual studio? I am in Visual Studio 2008.

I have a generic method:

```
public bool IsMemberProtected<T>(Expression<Func<T, object>> expression)
```

Would love to have a summary tag of something like this

> ```
>     /// <summary>
>     /// Determines whether a member is protected.
>     /// 
>     /// Usage: IsMemberProtected<ExampleType>(x => x.Member)
>     /// </summary>
> ```

But when I do that, the tooltip for the property no longer works when a developer hovers over the method in code to view the summary tag.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the entities `&lt;` and `&gt;` to give `<` and `>` respectively.

Notice that here you also use `<` and `>` to write a generic type. In this case there is a convention that if you use a `cref` tag then you can use `GenericType{T}` instead of the uglier `GenericType&lt;T&gt;`. See [here](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/91982/generics-and-xml-comments-do-not-mix) for more information.

Also from that page there is another suggestion if you have to write a lot of `<` and `>` symbols that you put the text in a CDATA section:

```
/// <summary>
/// This a simple collection which implements <see cref="IEnumerable{T}" />
/// </summary>
/// <example>
/// <![CDATA[
/// SimpleList<int> intList = new SimpleList<int>();
/// ]]>
/// </example>
```

Answer (score 1):

i think this may help you.

Right-click on the function, select "Document this" 
for Ex.

```
public void Function_Name()
```

becomes

```
/// <summary>
/// Give the details here
/// </summary>
/// <param name=""></param>
/// <returns> you can tel what it returns </returns>
public void Function_Name()
```

(it is all auto generated).